# I am able to ssh to remote server only if i am sudo

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh

I researched and found that to change mod of .ssh to 700 so

```
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ sudo cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ pwd
/home/ec2-user/.ssh
[ec2-user@ip-114 ~]$ cd ..

[ec2-user@ip-114 ~]$ chmod 700 .ssh/
[ec2-user@ip-114 ~]$ cd .ssh/
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ ssh -i "id_rsa.pub" ubuntu@x.x.x.x
Load key "id_rsa.pub": Permission denied
Permission denied (publickey).
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Even after change mod it saying permision denied.

If i do

```
sudo su
[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ sudo su
[root@ip-172-114 .ssh]# ssh  ubuntu@x.x.x.x
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Which is target behaviour for non root user.

Whats going wrong ?

Comment: As @mokugo-devops correctly wrote, these are wrong keys. Why are you using them? Have you generated them yourself? Normally there are no private keys on an instance. Where did they come from?

Comment: `ssh-keygen` i wanted to ssh to other instance from one instance

Comment: If you cp from root to ec2-user, also need to change owner: `chown ec2-user.ec2-user /home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: @Marcin perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to connect via the public key, you should be connecting via `id_rsa`.

Additionally please make sure it has permissions 400 with your user as the owner.

Comment: Hey. Thanku . but `[ec2-user@ip-114 .ssh]$ sudo ssh -i "/root/.ssh/id_rsa" ubuntu@X.X.X.X
` IS NOW WORKING but without sudo it say same permission denied

Comment: Hi, this is because your current user won;'t have permission to access `/root/.ssh`. Try moving it to `/home/ec2-user/id_rsa`. Then do a chmod 400 and set owner to ec2-user.

Comment: you mean `/home/ec2-user/.ssh/id_rsa` ?

Comment: Yes, the .ssh directory should have 700 permissions again for the local user (ec2-user in this case)